# How to click 'SwfObject' using UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

[image]

I want to click on a link `[Link name is 'Settlement']` and there are number of links on that page.

NOTE: Object spy does not identify 'Settlement' as the link instead it consider as Explorer Bar. When I take object spy on 'Settlement' text it highlights entire Explorer Bar due to which I am not able to get 'Settlement' specific properties. [refer attached screen shot. Due to security reason, I cannot upload a real screen shot].

Through recording, I am able to click 'Settlement' link

`SwfWindow("Platform Integration Exchange").SwfObject("mainExplorerBar").Click 133,598`

Currently, 133 & 598 are hard coded value for 'Settlement' but in future 'Settlement' position may change.

So I want to know, How can I click a 'settlement' link using X & Y co-ordinate where Object spy is not able to identify 'Settlement' link separately?.

OR is there any other way to click these type of objects?

Thanks
Onkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case I would recommend using a **virtual button** object.

In your UFT, go to:

Tools > Virtual Object >  New Virtual Object

Choose **"Button"** and click **"Mark Object"** Button. A cross hair cursor would appear and mark the object that you would like to map. Choose the area in the coorrdinates you would like to click.

When you are done, click **"Next"**.

Select the parent of the Virtual object and click **"Next"**.

Name the button, for example, "*myButton*", and name the collection in which you would like to store the virtual object and click **"Finish"**.

You can now use the"*myButton*" button in your script:

```
SwfWindow("Platform Integration Exchange").VirtualButton("myButton").Click
```

Comment: Hi Koby, Thanks for your solution and it worked for me.
Only one thing, As we know that virtual object works on the height and width of the object. If in the future, position of 'Settlement' change then will this solution work? Or Will I have to take a new virtual object for 'Settlement?

Comment: Happy this worked! Try making the virtual object as big as you can without the chance it will click other elements. If the position chhanges, just change the elements in the object repisitory. If this solution solved the problem, accepting my answer as correct would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Insight Objects. In my Project We are using swf application. For a part in application it's not getting identified, though it's one of the main part of Application. So we use Insight Object. It works perfectly fine.

else

You can use Click method only if separately identified as Swf Object

Syntax is : object.Click [X], [Y], [BUTTON]

X,Y,BUTTON are optional.
By default it's gonna Left Click.

X,Y are co-ordinates.

If you wanna different buttons to be clicked then use following.

```
0=micLeftBtn
1=micRightBtn
2=micMiddleBtn
```

For LeftClick :`SwfWindow("Form1").SwfObject("Object1").Click`
For Right Click :`SwfWindow("Form1").SwfObject("Object1").Click 1,1,1`
For Middle Click:`SwfWindow("Form1").SwfObject("Object1").Click 1,1,2`

Comment: Thanks Suman,I tried Insight object and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with powerbuilder application and I use the below function. I have modified it for your requirement

Public Function CLICKTEXTINSIDEOBJECT

```
Dim OperatedObject
Dim X1, X2, Y1, Y2

X1=0
X2=0
Y1=0
Y2=0

'get the object
Set OperatedObject = SwfWindow("Platform Integration Exchange").SwfObject("mainExplorerBar")

'get the co-ordinates of the text to be clicked
OperatedObject.GetTextLocation "Settlement",X1,Y1,X2,Y2

''Check if the Co-ordinates are assigned
if ((X1 > 0) or (Y1 > 0)) then
    OperatedObject.Click (X1 + X2)/2, (Y1+Y2)/2
    CLICKTEXTINSIDEOBJECT = true
Else
    CLICKTEXTINSIDEOBJECT = false
End If
```

End Function

Below is the description about the GetTextLocation object

http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/WindowsForms/SWFPACKAGELib~SwfObject.html#GetTextLocation

Comment: Hi Sumeet, 
Thanks for your solution but It is not working for me. I ran your code and got stuck at  
OperatedObject.Click (X1 + X2)/2, (Y1+Y2)/2
I got following error 
"The statement contains one or more invalid functions argument"
I am getting X1,X2,Y1 & Y3 values but not able to click.

Comment: Check, if the result of (X1+X2)/2 and (Y1+Y2)/2 is integer. Also if thats not working then you can simply click on the X1+5 and Y1+5 and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Sumeet, It worked ... Earlier I used to get co-ordinates in decimal. Not x1+5 is working for me... Thanks Once again